# What is a sentinel in the context of Firebase Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

`firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`

Returns a sentinel used with set() or update() to include a server-generated timestamp in the written data.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-servertimestamp

What exactly does the word 'sentinel' mean in this context?

Does it mean the value is a placeholder and the timestamp will be applied server-side?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're correct.  It's just a token value that has no specific value or meaning on the client, but has meaning on the server, and will be translated there at the time it's received.